# Javascript команды в адресную строку другого окна

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, такой вопрос. Допустим открываешь определенный сайт, в адресной строке набираешь "javascript: какие-то команды..", соответственно выполняются команды этого сайта, есть ли возможность не вручную это прописывать, а сделать это программно, то есть чтобы команды посылались в адресную строку этого сайта из написанного скрипта?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь ведётся в рамках одного домена, то попробуйте использовать метод [opener](http://javascript.ru/window.opener) объекта [window](http://javascript.ru/window). Например:

```
function nWindow(){
        var o = window.open('','','width=500 height=500');
            o.location.href=location.href+"/foo"; // здесь передаёте аргументы.
}
<input type="button" onclick="newWindow()" value="Нажми меня">
```

Если речь идёт о кросс-доменном способе, то "курите" [XDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd573303(v=vs.85).aspx).

Ну и несколько полезных ссылок:

- [Cross-domain «ajax» — простое решение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120336/)
- [Userscripts. Кроссдоменные запросы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130673/)
- [Обмен данными для документов с разных доменов](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-domain-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать новое окно (target="_blank") с конкретным содержимым, передав его в base64. На адресную строку можно влиять с помощью JavaScript — <code>window.location.href</code> .

Comment: не работает(
через window.open в новом окне открывается нужный сайт, как теперь туда заслать команду в адресную строку, допустим javascript:questinit(). если я введу ее вручную в то окно - все понятно сработает, а как сделать чтоб программно исполнять эту команду соответственно из другого окна, окна написанного скрипта?

Comment: window.location.href